# Edit rejected multiple times has same explanation by different people

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I recently was trying to help the community by editing. One of my edits was rejected. When I looked back, I noticed two people had rejected the question. However, both people wrote the exact same reason for rejecting the edit.

The edit was a valid one. I cleared up some things by adding commas and the like. I also fixed minor spelling and grammar errors.

Both users rejected more edits than they accepted, with one having rejected about 15 times the amount of edits as they had accepted.

The reason they posted was “The edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate, or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.”

I personally think this is ridiculous, but that isn’t the reason I’m asking the question.

Why did both people reject a seemingly valid edit for the exact same reason?

Here’s a screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Is the "to" in the title really unneeded? For me, as a non-native speaker, it reads a bit weird without it. Also, don't change "Thanks" to "Thank you" instead remove that. And to avoid confusion the review texts aren't written by hand, there is a set of system given texts the reviewer can chose from. That's why both reviewers have the same text.

Comment: Since the screenshot doesn't show the full question, I'll post a link to the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24248640

Comment: You’re right. The “to” probably should have stayed and the “Thanks” should have gone. But still, I think the edit was legitimate.

Comment: @Tom it's a confusing title in the first place, but the "to" shouldn't be there. It's "how to make X orbit around Y" or "how to make X to orbit around Y"

Comment: @TheWanderer Doesn't the title match your second example? Or do you mean "not" instead of "or"?

Comment: @Tom yes, sorry. I should've used "not" or "vs"

Comment: I'd have probably rejected it with the same reason - it's the "No Improvement whatsoever" pre-defined choice. All in all, there are two changes that do any improvement - making `Sphere` lowercase and *arguably* `code below` -> `Code`. The `to` and `info`  are superfluous changes, the `Thanks` -> `Thank you` is superfluous *and* wrong - the whole sentence should be gone. In fact, I'd remove the last three sentences. No need to remind people to ask questions, they'd do that without prompting.

Comment: Also, as for the comma you added - I believe that you missed another one `if you zoom out` should be surrounded with commas. Although, to be frank, I'm not completely sure. I'd prefer either both or neither but if the other edits were more substantial I wouldn't reject only for this.

Comment: Always remember that every edit you do (until you reach 3k) has to be reviewed by 3 people, so for minor edits you should always consider the time that others have to spend on your edit and weight in the *benefit* that the edit has. In this case, I don't think that this minorchange justifies  4 people x 30 seconds .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several predefined rejection reasons:

[image]

Having this list makes sure that it’s not too tedious for reviewers to give a good rejection reason. (Tag edits also have predefined rejection reasons but they are different.)

Also, the blue “1” shows up next to the previous reviewer’s rejection reason, if there was one.

The particular reason chosen for your edit just translates to “the edit was too minor”. Some of what you changed didn’t make the post *more* correct, such as *info* -> *information*. You also didn’t remove “thanks for your time” which is fluff and unnecessary (instead you changed the wording slightly).

Comment: On "thank you"  removal: in particular whole "I hope that my explanation is not too complex. If you need more info feel free to ask. Thanks for your time." section should have been removed rather than fixing...

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I would have used "Reject and Edit" in order to correct the problems in the question.

Certainly, in any case, I would have rejected these edits. Any edits that

1. Are incorrect (removing "to" in the title)
2. Do not remove excess text, but instead add even more ("Thanks change to "Thank you" when the entire sentence should be removed)

should not be approved.

The reason for the same rejection text is, as pointed out in comments, "boiler-plate". Reviewers only write their own rejection reasons if "Causes harm" is used.

Comment: +0, I think "how to make an object orbit around this other object" is correct, so removing "to" was ok, even though they should have corrected the whole title.